md class spacebarr cannot be removed
    body {
        font-family: 'DM Sans Variable', sans-serif;
        background-image: url('/assets/noise-texture.svg');
        @apply grid bg-gray-950 bg-repeat text-gray-50;
    }

   .glass-container {
        position: relative;
    }

   .glass-container::before {
        @apply absolute -inset-[10px] -z-10 rounded-xl border border-gray-100/20 bg-gray-200/10                backdrop-blur-md;
       content: '';
}

.signal-line {
    --rotation: 90deg;
    @apply h-[20px] w-[1.5px] bg-gradient-to-t md: h-[1.5px] md: w-[30px] lg: w-[40px] xl: w-[50px];
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1);
    background-image: linear-gradient( var(--rotation), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, #c39dff 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70%);
    background-size: 500% 500%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .signal-line {
        --rotation: 0deg;
    }
}

I cannot remove spacing on md class, eventhough ive been deleting those after save the code. md class suddenly making a space like this  md:h-[1.5px] to  md: h-[1.5px]. this file is on src/app.css. Using stelve framework with prismic tutorial in this link "https://youtu.be/v5Ncz5AcXjI?si=bkkplZJpTnlrsmB2". Plese help me programmer master, im just nebie nerd no friends. Im very appreciate it :))
